# Writing an equivalent functions by leveraging currying

Tags: haskell, currying

i am studying Haskell and I do not understand why the following two implementation are not equivalent. Rather why I get the error message if I try to load it in REPL.

```
addStuff :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
addStuff x y = x + y + 5

addStuff_ :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
addStuff_ x = x + (\i -> i + 5)
```

The erro I get is the following

```
   • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’
                  with actual type ‘a0 -> a0’
    • The lambda expression ‘\ i -> i + 5’ has one argument,
      but its type ‘Integer’ has none
      In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘(\ i -> i + 5)’
      In the expression: x + (\ i -> i + 5)
```

Comment: Why do you think they should be equivalent?

Comment: In a sense that same input produce  same output. I notice I had an error on what I was trying to do in addStuff_ signature

Comment: In the first equation you use `+` between numbers and numbers, in the second `+` occurs between a number and a function. That's a type error.

Comment: You can't add an integer and a function; `y + 5` is not the same as `\i -> i + 5`.

Comment: @AngeloBad can you show how these two functions produce the same output given the same input? For example give them the inputs 3 and 4 and then show a list of intermediate steps of the computation. If you do that we can probably point out which step goes wrong.

Comment: You are probably looking for `(\i -> x + i + 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second function is trying to sum `Integer` with another function. What you are looking for is function composition (using [`.`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.) operator):

```hs
addStuff_ :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
addStuff_ x = (x +) . (+ 5)
```

Or just:

```hs
addStuff' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
addStuff'  = (+) . (+ 5)
```